# How to autorun a C# mono applications on Raspberry PI startup?

Tags: linux, startup, mono, c#

I have a **Raspberry PI** running **Raspbian** and I connect to it through RDP or SSH. And I have 2 **applications in C#** and I run them through **mono**. One is a **WinForms app** (GUI app, which cannot be launched through SSH, since it requires a desktop environment) and the second is a console app (still running waiting for remote commands [editor's note: probably a daemon?]). Both apps write some logs to terminal window [stdout].

I'm launching them like this: `sudo mono app1`, `sudo mono app2`. I've created scripts with these commands in their app's folders. Like `~/Projects/App1/launcher`, `~/Projects/App2/launcher`.

I'd like to **run them on every boot** (every time RPI is (re)started and completely booted up). But I'd like to see those apps, if I connect through RDP or at least have a possibility to restart them manually.

I've read something about `rc.init` and `init.d` and that I can write commands there, but also I've read that that programs must not need user input, because the system won't be able to boot up otherwise and therefore I was afraid that my apps will break the system.

I'd like just a simple functionality like in Windows, where you can copy launchers to **"User/On startup" folder**.

Is there some easy solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

If your Raspi is setup to auto login a user, you could probably just add the launchers to the `~/.xsessionrc` of the user which is automatically logged in.

That way you would probably also see them in your RDP session, if you are exporting the running X session (the one identified as `:0`) in your RDP server.